# how to use C++ - UWP, WINRT methods in C++ - UWP, DLL application

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

1. How to call C++-UWP, WINRT methods in C++-UWP, DLL project? or
2. How to call C#-UWP methods in C++-UWP, DLL project?

Mainly, i want to call C# methods from C++-UWP, DLL application. Can somebody help me.

I can able to call the C# methods in C++-UWP, WINRT project but i want to use those in C++-UWP, DLL project.

Comment: Are you looking to author Windows Runtime components (dll) with C#? If yes, this is explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/authoring